# CAPTCHA bypass issue

Tags: bug, stackexchange, captcha

For a while now I have been noticing this, and not just on the SE network, but all the sites that use the new re-CAPTCHA system, and I have tested this on many different OSs and also many different browsers, but the problem still remains, most of the time if I click on the button which should give me a CAPTCHA test, it just does its spinning thing, then shows a big green tick and allows me to continue without actually testing me (this happens probably 98% of the time). So where should I report this issue?

Comment: It's a feature not a bug ;) I believe how it really works is not publicised by Google. Try it in private mode (aka incognito), it will most likely give you a test to make sure you're human.

Comment: It always tests me, probably due to a large collection of cookie n script blockers - why I keep having to identify pizza is beyond me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is part of reCaptcha's system, I believe.  And because of that, the people to report that issue to is reCaptcha, especially if it's global across all the reCaptcha things you see.

[The developer's FAQ for this is here.](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq)  They also have a [discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/recaptcha) on reCaptcha where you would likely go to report issues with reCaptcha.

Note that I don't think they *always* force you to do a captcha check, at least not on all sites.  I get reCaptchas on some sites that require actual captcha checks, others I just have to click the box. (Although I never have to captcha check here on StackExchange sites.)